# NServiceBus: How to configure MSMQ myself (not using runmefirst.bat)

Tags: nservicebus

I don’t want to use RunMeFirst.bat because I have no idea what it is doing, and I worry it is setting some permissions that I don’t want it to set (too permissive maybe?)

Can anyone tell me how to do this myself (via script) so I can have more control?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell would be a good option.  You have access to anything you would in .NET, so using System.Messaging.MessageQueue is available and you can configure it however you want.